# jsoup get values based on div tag id

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have an html which has tags as follows.

```
 parent   <li class="pro pic notSold" status="0" >
 child      <ul><li></li><ul>
 parent   <li class="pro pic soldOut" status="-1" >
 child      <ul><li></li><ul>
```

there are multiple parent

tags as above. I want my loop to work for all

parent tags.
I tried, Elements indProducts = html.select("li"); This was pulling even the child li. I dont want that.
I want to code such that if the

class starts with pro pic, then it would be considered else skip. What should I do? Is there a select clause that works similar to "like" or something like that.

Comment: You can check if attribute starts with a certain text -- it's all in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, jSoup provides something similar to like. Check out this [selector](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) usage link.

You could try something like this:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class JSoupTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         String html =   "<li class='pro pic notSold' status='0' >";
         html+=      "<ul><li></li><ul>";
         html+=   "<li class='pro pic soldOut' status='-1' >";
         html+=      "<ul><li></li><ul>";

         Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
         Elements elems = doc.select("[class^=pro pic]");

        System.out.println(elems.size());
    }
}
```

***`Output = 2`***

**Note:** Your `class` starting with `pro pic` is too generic and will return the outermost parent (and also one inner child).

Answer (score 0):

This is more precise, just selects tags li for which the class attributes starts with pro pic:

```
Elements litags = yourcontent.select("li[class^=pro pic]");
```

Or if you want to be sure that you take only the first level of childrens you can use this:

```
Elements litags = yourcontent.select(" > li[class^=pro pic]");
```

*PS: I tested with yourcontent as Element. I don't know if works for Elements.